# Object doesn't support property or method 'Deferred' in IE

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am using the jQuery 1.6.2 form plug-in and using an ajax submit function to submit a form including an image upload function. In every browser, this functions properly, but in IE9, when trying to submit the form, "Object doesn't support property or method 'Deferred' in IE" error occurs. The ajax submit function is shown below.

```
            jQuery('#el-add-press-review-form').ajaxSubmit({
            url:baseurl+profile_url+'/rr/add',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    show_messages(data.status,data.msg);
                    jQuery(data.html).hide().prependTo('.el- main-press-review-container').fadeIn(800);

                    lenthOffieldset=jQuery('.el-main-press-review-container').children("fieldset").length;
                    jQuery('.catalog-message').hide();
                    /*if(lenthOffieldset>5){
                        //jQuery('.el-main-press-review-container fieldset:last').remove();
                        jQuery('.el-load-more-press-reviews').show();
                        jQuery('.el-load-more-press-reviews').html('Load More');
                    } 
                    else{
                        jQuery('.el-load-more-press-reviews').hide();
                    }*/
                    lastpressReviewId=jQuery('.el-main-press-review-container fieldset:last').attr('press_review_id');
                    jQuery('.el-load-more-press-reviews').attr('last_press_review',lastpressReviewId);
                    //show_messages(data.status,data.msg);
                    jQuery.unblockUI();
                }
                else if(data.status == 401){
                    redirect_login_timed_out();
                } 
                else {
                    show_messages(data.status,data.msg);
                }   
            },
            error:function(){
                jQuery.unblockUI();
            }
        })
        jQuery('.dialogAddPressReview').dialog('close');
    }
});
```

Need to know why the above stated error is occurring.

Comment: I can't find `ajaxSubmit` in the documentation. Is that a plugin?

Comment: I can't see any call to `deferred` On which line does that occur?

Comment: Which plugin does `unblockUI` come from?

Comment: 'Deferred' has been declared in the jQuery form library (plug-in)

Comment: Links to the relevant plugins, please

Comment: ajaxSubmit is a function declared in a plug-in jQuery.form.js. It is used to upload an image.